# How to use QScopedPointer in lambda function?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I created a widget object using QScopedPointer utility and used it in a lambda connect function. As a result, it generated a compile time error.

```
 QScopedPointer<QMessageBox> errBox(new QMessageBox());
    errBox->setText("some text");
    QObject::connect(errBox,&QMessageBox::buttonClicked,this,[=](QAbstractButton *button){
        qInfo()<<"clicked button"<<button->text();
    });
```

However when I replaced QScopedPointer with normal initialization it worked perfectly.

```
QMessageBox *errBox = new QMessageBox();
errBox->setText("some text");
QObject::connect(errBox,&QMessageBox::buttonClicked,this,[=](QAbstractButton *button){
    qInfo()<<"clicked button"<<button->text();
});
```

I explored Qt Docs and found that:

> The code the compiler generates for QScopedPointer is the same as when
> writing it manually. Code that makes use of delete are candidates for
> QScopedPointer usage (and if not, possibly another type of smart
> pointer such as QSharedPointer). QScopedPointer intentionally has no
> copy constructor or assignment operator, such that ownership and
> lifetime is clearly communicated.

I want to know the reason for compilation error. Is there some other way to use QScopedPointer in lambda?
What am I missing here?

Comment: Is the text of the compile time error a secret for a reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in the lambda. The problem is that, like `std::unique_ptr`, `QScopedPointer` does not cast automatically to a pointer, so your compiler probably complains about not finding a `QObject::connect` taking a `QScopedPointer`. Try:

```
QObject::connect(errBox.get(), ...
```